# CSS3: применение сегодня, стоит ли делать акцент?

Tags: css3, вёрстка

Сейчас оканчиваю подготавливать макет сайта, и возник вопрос, который меня упорно преследует: а стоит ли сейчас применять в своем проекте CSS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS3 - это технология, которая УЖЕ принята и официально поддерживается всеми популярными броузерами, если и не на все 100%, то  в скором будущем будет поддерживаться полностью.

Я бы делал упор на CSS3.

Но всё зависит от проекта. Какую часть пользователей будут составлять старые броузеры и куча других нюансов...

Answer (score 2):

Если вы не хотите оказаться на дне, а на гребне волны, то лучше использовать сейчас, чем потом переписывать сайт. Сейчас уже все новые браузеры поддерживают CSS3, а со старыми идет борьба. Пишите в CSS3 и HTML5 не бойтесь, написав сейчас вы не будете ломать голову над тем что потом надо будет переписывать и будете иметь больше возможностей от этих технологий.

Answer (score 2):

Люди пишите все на html5 и css3! Не делайте поддержку старых браузеров. Может вместе мы победим IE6,7 и прочих динозавров!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю да, упор стоит сделать, но так чтобы при неправельном браузере общая картинка не портилась. так же есть куча фильтров и хаков для различных браузеров, на практике можно сделать поддержку CSS3 для IE браузеров специальными скриптами типа PIE, писать условия типа

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='ie6.css' /><![endif]-->
```

В общем экспериментируйте, лишним не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Заказчики бывают разными, одни думают раз плачу деньги, то пусть поддерживают все и ие6 в том числе. Другие наоборот понимают, что нельзя тащить на сайт кучу картинок для уголочков и теней, что если пользователи ие их не увидят, то не помрут, зато сайт будет быстрее грузиться и работать (правда таких заказчиков не много и их нужно еще убедить, что они выиграют от использования css3). Нужно также понимать, что пользователей ие6-7 с каждым днем становиться все меньше (правда ие8 еще долго будет, а он тоже обделен поддержкой css3) поэтому нужно быть готовым использовать новые возможности.